# Creating levels for age in survival analysis

Tags: r

I'm running survival analysis in R and would want to predict the survival times for age groups e.g. 20-29; 30-39; 40-49 etc. and BMI 15-18.5; 19-24.9; 25-29.9 etc. I need help on putting age and BMI in group to do the analysis.

```
Event  Time  Age  Bmi   Gender  Smoke  Stroke
0      80    16   16.5  2       0      2
1      79    19   18.5  1       1      2
0      80    21   20    2       0      2
1      79    23   23    1       1      1
0      80    34   34    2       0      1
1      79    37   35    1       1      1
0      80    43   22    2       0      1
1      79    48   24    1       1      2
0      80    52   41    2       0      2
1      79    54   45    1       1      2
```

Comment: give data example we can use (use `dput()`), use SO formatting please

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Grouping variables like this causes severe loss of statistical power.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test without the data but that should be the idea:

```
breaks_age <- seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 10)
breaks_bmi <- seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 5)
df$cutpoint_age <- cut(df$age,breaks=breaks_age , right=FALSE)
df$cutpoint_BMI <- cut(df$BMI,breaks=breaks_bmi , right=FALSE)
```

Comment: @Stone, so please mark it as resolved, click the grey check under the downvote button.